# Is there a way to count the operations it took to complete a certain part of a program?

Tags: c#, .net, code-analysis, system.diagnostics

Out of curiosity I'm trying to find out how many operations it takes for a certain method to complete.

More clear and concise than before:

```
doThis();
doAswell();
doToo();
```

I want to know how many arithmetic operations, that means actual processor actions it takes to get from calling **doAswell();** to completing it.

```
private void doAswell()
{
    int counter = 0;
    while(counter < 1000)
        counter++;
}
```

This for example taking about 2000 ALU-steps (1000 compares + 1000 increments) + some overhead for allocation of *counter*.
Obviously I am looking to do this on more complex operations(constructors, etc.), which actually take multiple ALU-steps for one operation.

My question:
Can I at all count the operations performed between two points in a program?
And if so: How?

Comment: What do you consider a "operation"? Also are you looking for [Wall-Clock Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall-clock_time) or [CPU Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_time)?

Comment: Have a look at this SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11504438/correct-way-to-use-performancecounter-in-net-to-measure-cpu-usage

Comment: @ScottChamberlain by "operation" I mean: One action of the ALU. **add register 0x33 to 0xA4, store in 0xAA**. Or is this approach not possible in higher languages like C#? (I come froma C/assembler-heavy background)

Comment: This would be different per-platform, possibly per architecture (32/64 bit), per .net version, per processor (manufacturer or model, potentially) and a dozen other variables. If you're looking to measure  performance, this is not a good way to do it - and if you just want a ballpark figure for educational purposes, you're probably better off estimating it by hand.

Comment: Don't fall in to the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), explain to us what you are trying to accomplish that measuring the number of actions on the ALU would be the solution and let us help you with *that* problem instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interpretation of the question: how many instructions are executed to perform an operation.

If correct:

C# is compiled to MSIL. You can inspect the generated MSIL using ILSpy. This can give a rough indication.

Generated MSIL is however not executed directly but passed to the JIT that converts the MSIL to instruction understood by the ALU. I don't know if there is way to see the instructions after the JIT. Never had the need for it.

Other option is to use NGEN on the assembly. NGEN creates a binary with native instructions for the target platform. You can use a disassembler on the output.

But my guess is that the curiosity is there from a performance perspective.

Influencing the JIT on codegeneration is not trivial (if doable).

Use a profiler to find the bottleneck and alter the C# code to improve performance is the most trivial and maintainanble way imho.

If there is no way to get the needed performance try to recode the needed parts in C(++).

C# is a high-level language and the level of abstraction adds some level of overhead. The JIT is however quite smart, outperforming it with handcrafted code is a challenge.

Comment: Your interpretation is correct. I'll give ILSpy and NGEN a shot. I'm not running into bottlenecks at the moment, but just want to do some research on performance. Also since I come from a C/Assembler heavy background I am curious what those comfortable and smooth high-level tools do behind the scenes.